# How to read Chinese formatting from CSV?

Tags: tables, formatting, csvsimple, chinese

Does anyone know which package I can implement to be able to read Chinese characters from a CSV file. The code works really well with English, but as soon as a make a CSV file containing Chinese formatted characters, it refuses to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    every head row/.style={%
        before row={\hline
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Vocab} & \\
        },
        after row=\hline
    },
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    columns/name/.style={column name=English, column type=l},
    columns/surname/.style={column name=Pinyin, column type=l},
    columns/age/.style={column name=Chinese, column type=c},
    ]{test.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried adding this package

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
{\CJKfamily{bkai}老闆來碗麵條。}
\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

but couldn't get it to work. Each works fine on their own, but I cannot get them to work together. The CSV files are made in notepad and saved as `UFT8 csv`.

Thanks for reading,

BR Mark